# How to solve CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException with setMultiChoiceItems - Android

Tags: android

I want an alertDialog with multi choices items (items from my DB), but when I use it, I have  this error: "android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2".

My code to get data from db:

```
public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME_2,null);
    return res;
}
```

My DB:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME_2 = "word_table";
public static final String COL1_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL1_2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL1_3 = "VALUE";
public static final String COL1_4 = "ISSELECTED";

db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_2 +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,VALUE TEXT,ISSELECTED INTEGER)");
```

My code using multichoiceit

```
Cursor res = db.getAllData();
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(res,res.getString(3),res.getString(1),new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface parent, int position,
                            boolean checked) {

        }

    });
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.show();
```

error message (I have only 2 records in my db):

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2
```

thank a lot for your help!

Comment: Please tell the values of `res.getString(3)` and  `res.getString(1)`.

Comment: Add your TABLE_NAME_2 structure it seems you have only two column but you indexed at third column.

Comment: Done, look at "My DB".

Comment: Check if the cursor is empty & use cursor.moveToFirst() to get starting index.

Comment: look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812030/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-column-id-does-not-exist) & probably see this [answer also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5812106/4824088)

Comment: `Cursor res = db.getAllData();`. Unreadable code. Please change to `Cursor cursor = db.getAllData();`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( res.getCount() < 4 )
    return;

res.getString(3) // can safely be called now
```

but then i do not understand your code as the definition is

```
 public AlertDialog.Builder setMultiChoiceItems (Cursor cursor
   , String isCheckedColumn, String labelColumn
   , DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener listener)
```

I would rather think you would call it like:

```
 builder.setMultiChoiceItems(res, "0", "1", .....         
 builder.setMultiChoiceItems(res, "ischecked", "label", .....
```

As you now posted

```
public static final String COL1_3 = "VALUE";
public static final String COL1_4 = "ISSELECTED";
```

It should be:

```
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(res, COL1_4, COL1_3, .....
```

Comment: Where do I put that?

Comment: Before use of the statement or function that causes the index out of bounds exception.

Comment: Cursor: the cursor used to provide the items.

isCheckedColumn : specifies the column name on the cursor to use to determine whether a checkbox is checked or not. It must return an integer value where 1 means checked and 0 means unchecked.

labelColumn : The column name on the cursor containing the string to display in the label.

The problem come from my cursor... But I dont know why.